# Ugly water shader which is not influenced by the directional light

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, lighting

I recently started working with unity and tried making my first real water shader with shader graph (URP).
In general it works fine, but I have some really ugly effects with the lighting.
First, when I set the smoothness of the water to about 1 (to make it shiny as water is), it is "split into two areas" (see the screenshot). One is nice and looks like water, the rest is grey. Why?

[image]

Second, when I turn the Global Directional Light to night time, the land is dark, the water isn't. Why?

[image]

Here you also can see this "grey water effect".

This is my shader graph
[image]
and these are my environment settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found a part of the solution: The problem with the ugly reflection was that the water plane had a Y scale of 0. When I change it to something greater than 0, it works.
But that does not solve that it isn't affected by the environment light.